# :NERDTreeFind errors out with E492: Not an editor command: NERDTreeFind

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Installed the NERDTree plugin (scrooloose/nerdtree) from github. It works great except features like :NERDTreeFind fail to work. Even thought it is listed on the help sections.

VIM error: 
"E492: Not an editor command: NERDTreeFind"

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't install the plugin properly. I just installed it an the command works for me. How did you install the plugin?

Comment: Pretty standard install. NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed the below two files from an older NERDTree install.

~/.vim/doc/NERD_tree.txt

~/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim

Removed the above files and reinstalled the plugin using.

NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

That fixed the issue.

Thank you.